# Android Httpclient redirection to another URL to get the HTML content of the webpage

Tags: android

I am able to login sucessfully to a webpage using user authentication but dont know how to redirect to another URL after successful login. I am using [this](http://postimage.org/profile.php) URL for login.  I am sucessful with login part but dont know how to redirect to other URL http://postimg.org/my.php?gallery=1cdkirjw after login is validated. How should I do that? Please help me..

```
String UrlLink2="http://postimg.org/my.php?gallery=1cdkirjw/";
            String UrlLink ="http://postimage.org/profile.php";
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                                           Login Page---->f    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UrlLink);
  Url Login             try {
     Page                String username = "xxxxxx";
                         String password = "yyyyyy";
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
    Is this part---->       HttpPost Newhttppost = new HttpPost(UrlLink2);
    correct     ---->       HttpResponse Newresponse = httpclient.execute(Newhttppost);
    to redirect ---->       InputStream is=Newresponse.getEntity().getContent();
    to another URL          String line = "";
                            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                             try {
                              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                                total.append(line); 
                              }
                             } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                             }
```

Comment: is your second url post or get ?

Comment: I agree with @HareshChhelana, it looks like that second request should be a get. Also, how is the authentication handled once logged in - your `is` variable doesn't seem to be used?

Comment: I dont know how to do authentication  for second url. Plz help trying it for so long not able get any idea..

Comment: Is there any way directly I can go to "http://postimg.org/my.php?gallery=1cdkirjw/" and check for authentication  instead of going to "http://postimage.org/profile.php" for login. If yes give me some idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use second async task for when you redirect it. i think you call another asynctask after first async task.